# how to copy contents from current tty to a file in Linux RHEL 6.3

Tags: linux, command-line

I am trying to copy the contents of on the current tty to a file by using command

```
ls -l > ls-l.txt
```

but I'm unable to get the output

Can any one help me how to copy content from screen(terminal) to file in linux ?

Comment: what happens when you enter the command `more ls-l.txt`?

Answer (score 1):

By using the command `ls -l > ls-l.txt` you redirect standard output to a file. So it is normal that you don't see the output of the command, but the file will surely contain it. If you also want to see the ouput, you should use the tee command from GNU coreutils:
 `ls -l | tee ls-l.txt`